# k-means algorithm not working

Tags: python, algorithm, k-means

I am trying to implement the k-means algorithm in Python 3 using Numpy. My input data matrix is a simple n x 2 data matrix of points:

```
[[1, 2],
 [3, 4],
   ...
 [7, 13]]
```

For some reason at each step in the iteration, none of my labels are the same. Every single label is different. Does anybody see anything overtly wrong that I'm doing? I tried to add some comments to my code so that people can understand the various steps I'm doing.

```
def kmeans(X,k):

    # Initialize by choosing k random data points as centroids
    num_features = X.shape[1]
    centroids = X[np.random.randint(X.shape[0], size=k), :] # find k centroids
    iterations = 0
    old_labels, labels = [], []

    while not should_stop(old_labels, labels, iterations):
        iterations += 1

        clusters = [[] for i in range(0,k)]
        for i in range(k):
            clusters[i].append(centroids[i])

        # Label points
        old_labels = labels
        labels = []
        for point in X:
            distances = [np.linalg.norm(point-centroid) for centroid in centroids]
            max_centroid = np.argmax(distances)
            labels.append(max_centroid)
            clusters[max_centroid].append(point)

        # Compute new centroids
        centroids = np.empty(shape=(0,num_features))
        for cluster in clusters:
            avgs = sum(cluster)/len(cluster)
            centroids = np.append(centroids, [avgs], axis=0)

    return labels

def should_stop(old_labels, labels, iterations):
    count = 0
    if len(old_labels) == 0:
        return False
    for i in range(len(labels)):
        count += (old_labels[i] != labels[i])
    print(count)
    if old_labels == labels or iterations == 2000:
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
max_centroid = np.argmax(distances)
```

You want to find the centroid that minimizes the distance, not the one that maximizes it.